# Why is the Boro Park eiruv controversial?

Tags: shabbat, chutz-laaretz, current-events, eruv-chatzerot

I know I might be hitting a touchy subject, but I'm prefacing it with this so I can clarify right away: I don't want a Psak, or who holds what. That's for each person to figure out... I just want to know what all the issues are with respect to the Boro Park eiruv, and **why** someone would hold what he does.

Comment: I'd retitle this, as "what's the story" is a bit too conversational.

Comment: @Ze'ev Felsen Is "Is the Boro Park Eiruv [mutar/assur]?" any better?

Comment: not bad...i feel like there's a better way to word it, but don't know what that is.

Comment: @Ze'ev But that's just as controversial, if not worse because I would be picking a side prematurely, or forcing the answerer [made up word] to pick a side. My current title is saying: "I don't want a yes/no answer -- just an explanation"

Comment: I would have said "what's the status of..." but it seems to ask if the eruv is up or not.  Perhaps "what's the story behind the controversy over..."  Is that too long?  Or "Why is the boro park eiruv controversial"?

Comment: @Ze'ev I don't see much of a difference, but if you *really* want to change it you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple good places to start would be [here](http://eruvonline.blogspot.com/2006/01/1981-boro-park-kol-korei-exposed_05.html) and [here](http://eruvonline.blogspot.com/2006/03/key-points-regarding-permissibility-of.html), both from the Eruv Blog.

The second link, which itself contains many relevant and detailed links, addresses the technical issues of the geography, demographics, and (artificial) geology of Brooklyn that govern the permissibility/restrictions of an *eruv*. The first link addresses a non-legal complication in the case regarding the authenticity of influential documents.

Answer (score 3):

The Main underlying Issue is, is Brooklyn and or New York City a Rishus Harabim Doraisia

Comment: So why would it would be, or wouldn't it be. What's the actual Machlokes? yeshiva tomorrow?

Comment: MOre in Depth see here:
[The New Queens Eiruv](http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Shlomo_Pearl/2011-01-09/The_New_Eruv_In_Quens/Rabbi__Shlomo_Pearl__The_New_Eruv_In_Quens__2011-01-09.wmv)

Comment: See the rebuttal of Rabbi Pearl [here](http://eruvonline.blogspot.com/2011/08/gezeiros-and-more-harav-shlomo-pearl.html).